# Can't change fields (set new values) of the object from an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have two functions. One is meant for getting an observable and the second for saving it. I would like to call the first function, extract the object from the corresponding observable, change some fields (set new values) of the object, and finally save the updated version.

The problem is that changes are not reflected. Both `console.log("Before", t.beginDate);` and `console.log("After", t.beginDate);` print the same values even though I assign new values to the object:

```
      let t: Entry;
      this.entryService.getEntry(id).subscribe(response => {
        t = response;
        console.log("Before", t.beginDate);
        t.beginDate = newStart;
        t.endDate = newEnd;
        console.log("After", t.beginDate);
        this.entryService.saveEntry(t).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
          res => console.log('success', res),
          err => console.error('error', err),
          () => {console.log("")});
      })
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `newStart` have a different value than `response.beginDate` ? Your looks like correct...

Comment: Yes, both `newStart` and `newEnd` have different values than the original ones. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm calling this function as a callback when an entry is dragged and then dropped?

Comment: I don't think so, depends of the logic of your code. Could you try to do ``onsole.log("Before", response.beginDate);` ? The value that is displayed is the one of the `newStart` var or the `response` ? Is that possible that your service is modifying the result ?